# How do I continuously retry a JSoup request?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, http-status-code-404

I am trying to use JSoup to get some data and write it to a file, however I have a requests that I need. Sometimes I get a 404 error (even with agent header).

How can I keep retrying the request until it works and only write to the text file when I know it successfully received a response?

The code I have is below.

```
        for (String link : listOfLinks(doc)) {
                try {
                    Document doc= Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

                    Elements ps = doc.select("p");

                    writeTextToFile(ps.text());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I have tried putting it wrapped in a loop, perhaps I am not doing it correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your code in a function, you can simply call it again when it fails. So it could look something like this:

```
    function GetData(){
    for (String link : listOfLinks(doc)) {
            try {
                Document doc= Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

                Elements ps = doc.select("p");

                writeTextToFile(ps.text());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               //Retry 
               GetData()
            }
        }
   }
   GetData()//Start the initial attempt
```

This should keep running until it works without errors. You could also add a timeout so it waits one second or so before retrying if that would help. So instead of just:

```
//Retry 
GetData();
```

It would be:

```
//Retry after 1000 milliseconds
setTimeout(GetData, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: You're welcome! Did that work for you? Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid that this approach is going into loop.

Comment: This is the idea isn't it @DarkSkull? To keep looping until it succeeds. If it succeeds it does stop.